# Python subprocess module use

Tags: python, subprocess

How do you specify what directory the python module subprocess uses to execute commands? I want to run a C program and process it's output in Python in near realtime.

I want to excute the command (this runs my makefile for my C program:

```
make run_pci
```

In:

```
/home/ecorbett/hello_world_pthread
```

I also want to process the output from the C program in Python. I'm new to Python so example code would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
Edward

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `cwd` argument to `Popen`, `call`, `check_call` or `check_output`. E.g.

```
subprocess.check_output(["make", "run_pci"],
                        cwd="/home/ecorbett/hello_world_pthread")
```

**Edit**: ok, now I understand what you mean by "near realtime". Try

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["make", "run_pci"],
                     stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                     cwd="/home/ecorbett/hello_world_pthread")
for ln in p.stdout:
    # do processing
```

Comment: Thanks! Now how would I capture output from the c program? It simply printfs multiplule lines of text?

Comment: If you read the documentation you will see that check_output returns the output of the command. http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output

Comment: I see. so doing something like this:                            process = subprocess.check_output(["make","run_pci"],cwd="/home/ecorbett/hello_world_pthread")
print process.communicate()                                                      Would be unnecessary/incorrect?

Comment: But back to my original question. If my C program will be running, processing data and producing output that I need to process with my python program simultaneously, will this method still work?

Comment: @NASAIntern: no, then you need to use `Popen` instead of `check_output`. Pass it `stdout=subprocess.PIPE`, then read from its `stdout` member.

Comment: Ok. Im gonna give that a try!

Comment: Like this: p = subprocess.Popen(["make", "run_pci"],stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                        cwd="/home/ecorbett/hello_world_pthread")

output = p.stdout.read()

Comment: I see it! Ok, let me try that!

Comment: Excellent that works! But will it work if I need to process the output in python while the C programming is still running?

Comment: @NASAIntern: if your OS does proper multitasking, then yes.

Comment: @NASAIntern: I see you've changed the answer to refer to your own program. If this program exhibits the behavior you describe, then you should change it to use line-buffered output.

Comment: @NASAIntern: this is beyond what I can explain in a comment box.

Answer (score 0):

Read [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor).  You can specify it with the `cwd` argument, otherwise it uses the current directory of the parent (i.e., the script running the subprocess).